# Unable to set values for custom fields in template

Tags: docusignapi

My use case is simple. I want to create custom fields in my template and use it to create documents with different values in it by filling the custom fields based on the recipient. I am trying to set the custom field "test" with some value in my template and it is not reflecting in the created document. I am unable to understand if I am making any mistake here, because I am exactly doing what the api sample have suggested.

API - **demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1938032/envelopes**

```
{
  "accountId": "1938032",
  "emailSubject": "API Example - Populating Data in Templates",
  "templateId": "1bd2b688-b88f-445f-adf8-f5b462cf6dbb",
  "templateRoles": [{
    "email": "raghavneon@gmail.com",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "roleName": "test",
    "tabs": {
      "textTabs": [ {
        "tabLabel": "test",
        "value": "kasdfasdfadsfadsfads"
      }]
    }
  }],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Comment: please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an existing template you need to have the field (tab) defined in the template itself and named the same exact `tabLabel` that you provide in your API request. In other words, looking at your request you need to have a text field defined somewhere in your template that has a label of `"test"` for your JSON to work.

On the other hand, if you were not using a template then you'd be able to pre-populate like this:

```
{
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "Basic Tabs Example",
    "documents": [{
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "contract.pdf",
        "documentBase64": "base64 document bytes...",
    }],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "email": "john@email.com",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [{
                    "tabLabel": "test",
                    "value": "12345",                    
                    "xPosition": "75",
                    "yPosition": "50",
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "pageNumber": "1"
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```